# Im facing problem in making a calculator using REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Gmw.png)

From the above image u can see that on the right side there is a console in which state object is there.

now in state object-
 - check key is to make sure that if i add an operator (+,-,*,/) then it will become true
 - count is to count the number of brackets
 - decIsThere is become true when i insert decimal in input so that i dont place more then one decimal in a number, so if decisThere is true then decimal will not appear but i reset the value of this when i add an operator so as to enable the decimal again for once 
 - eTenIsThere is to make sure that i use E (exp of 10) for once like (3E10) so it also works same as decIsThere
 - input: it is an empty string which changes when i press the buttons in calculator 
 - opr: is an array consist ['+','-','*','/']
 - forget about the last one 'oprStatus'

Now my problem begins when i press 'C' button. 'C' button is used to delete the last input value from value of 'input' key

i used slice method for that

```
class Body extends Component {
 state= {
   input: '',
   decIsThere: false,
   opr: ['+','-','*','/','^'],
   oprStatus: false,
   check: false,
   eTenIsThere: false,
   count: 0
 }

delete= () => {
  var op= this.state.input
  var opLength= op.length
  this.ifOpr()
  if(op[opLength-1]==='.' ) {
    this.setState({
      decIsThere: false
    })
  }
  else if (op[opLength-1]==='E') {
    this.setState({
      eTenIsThere: false,
      decIsThere: false
    })
  }

  this.setState((prev) => ({
    input: prev.input.slice(0,-1)
  }))
}
```

So for example if i want to delete an input :  '2.3+4.5'

so i can delete it but i need to make sure the value of 'decIsThere' should be true when i delete '+' so that i cant insert decimal value as '2.3' already has decimal value and thus its a mathematical error if i mention for example '2.3.5'

i hope i explained my problem clearly

i know one solution which is :

if i delete '+' then a for loop will execute which will check whether there is an another operator or not if there is then it will check from the operator it searched till the total length of the string 
and if there is a decimal present then it will change the value of 'decIsThere' to true.

but idk my brain is like stopped working and thus i decided to post my problem here T-T

Comment: Try and rephrase the question and description to be specific to the problem. "Im makin a calculator" isn't a question. Describing what the actual problem _is_ may even help you solve it on your own.